# Why changing nullable values to double cause Clickhouse tables became read-only frequently?

Tags: clickhouse

Guys, I have been working with clickhouse for a while and clickhouse is running pretty well on our prod environment, but last week, I tried to change the value of 5 columns from null to a double value, and the affected rows are about 3600, the sql is like 'alter table XXX update columnA = 1.11 where timestamp = '2022-01-01 08:00:00'

Then wired things happen, all the prod clickhouse tables became read-only mode, I checked the log and found the zookeeper is complaining about out of memory, after I increased the jvm of zookeeper, the tables are still kept read-only mode, so I checked the zookeeper nodes and found a mutation znode containing huge amount of data in the table I tried to do mutation operations. After I deleted the mutation znode, clickhouse gradually became stable but still slow.

It's after I checked the replication-queue table in system database, and delete the /queue znode in zookeeper, the clickhouse insert and read speed became much faster, I think it's because too much merging operations stuck in the queue made clickhouse insertion became much slower.

So finally our clickhouse is working well again now in the prod environment, but I still did not get it, why my mutation operations of changing null values to double would cause this tragedy?

Does anyone has any idea about this issue?[image]

Comment: Questions - Queries run `ON CLUSTER`? and if so, what cluster do you have? (number of shards/replicas)
Server resources? The number of affected rows in the mutation?

Comment: 1. to try to answer why your mutation could have created this problem. First it depends on your cluster configuration, and number of partitions that were impacted by your change. The more partitions, the bigger the impact. if you are saying that only 3600 rows are to be updated, but they are all on different partitions, it would mean the mutation will have to rewrite all this partitions on disk, which means a lot of IO + RAM used(to sort).2nd there's a limit in the number of mutation clickhouse can handle at once, if you reached that limit, your tables will become read-only like you mentioned.

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/15882#issuecomment-707434029